# is it okay to disconnect Antminer like S7 >

Tags: miner-configuration, antminer

I have a kind of unstable internet connection
sometimes it gets disconnected for over an hour 
the question here is , does that hour of mining without internet count ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you aren't connected to the internet you can't submit shares to your pool, so you won't earn anything during that time period. That's why it's recommended for miners to have fast, low latency connections.

Answer (score 0):

No, while mining it should stay online.

If it gets disconnected, then you don't need to do anything, it'll connect once the internet is back up.

Comment: and what about the time it was mining without internet ? was it just working and consuming power without any benefit ? or it will upload the mined coinz  when it gets connected ? thank thank you

Comment: It won't mine, it'll just check whether internet connection came back.